# Webpack class priority

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I use a webpack(with ES5 to ES6 transpile) and trying to build bundle.js.
But i get an error message in Chrome: *index.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: Grid is not defined*

My **entry point**(index.js):

```
require('./Grid');
new Grid();
```

My **class**(Grid.js)

```
export class Grid
{
    constructor()
    {
        alert('Hello World');
    }
}
```

**Webpack config**:

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, "src/js"),
    devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
    entry: __dirname + '/src/js/index.js',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                   presets: ['es2015']
               }
            }
       ]
   },
   output: {
       path: __dirname + "/dist/js/",
       filename: "bundle.js"
   }
};
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use Babel's `export`, you have to be careful using `require`. This is how CommonJS works in a few different situations:

```js
// Classic CommonJS default export
module.exports = Grid;
// Import with one of:
import Grid from './Grid.js';
const Grid = require('./Grid.js');

// Babel ES6 default export
export default class Grid {}
// Import with one of:
import Grid from './Grid.js';
const Grid = require('./Grid.js').default; // Babel exports it as named property default
// The export is more or less equivalent to (but you shouldn't write this yourself)
module.exports = { default: Grid, __esModule: true }; // (__esModule is a Babel internal)

// Named CommonJS/ES6 export:
module.exports = { Grid: Grid };
// Equivalent to
export class Grid {} // no default = export named
// or 
export { Grid }; // with Grid created earlier
// Import with one of:
import { Grid } from './Grid.js';
const Grid = require('./Grid.js').Grid;
```

This was changed with the introduction of Babel 6 if I'm not mistaken. Babel 5 exported default properties the same way classic CommonJS does default exports. To better implement the ES6 spec it was changed.

Answer (score 1):

The following two changes seemed to fix the problem for me:

1. `Grid.js`: Change `export class Grid...` to `module.exports = class Grid...`.
2. `index.js`: Change `require('./Grid');` to *either* `var Grid = require('./Grid');` *or* `import Grid from './Grid';`.